# Allow a remote control to work while on lock screen

Tags: banshee, lock-screen, remote-control

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to allow key functions while desktop locked](https://askubuntu.com/questions/122903/how-to-allow-key-functions-while-desktop-locked)

I'm looking for a solution to the following problem. I use a remote control to pause/skip music that I am playing in Banshee, and this works well. However, when my computer locks, due to inactivity, the remote control no longer works.

Does anyone know of a way to fix this problem? I believe the remote control simply triggers specific keyboard buttons to be pressed, which handle that action. Is there a program that can run in the background which could do this? I still would really like my computer to lock after a period of inactivity.

Thank you.