# How do I bind a key to a command on the lock screen?

Tags: shortcut-keys, lock-screen

I want to bind a key when the lock screen is up (or the screensaver is on). My machine is often locked and I want to be able to hit a shortcut to run a script in my home directory.

I've used System Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts to bind keys to trigger the lock screen, but when the screensaver is on or the lock screen is up, my custom shortcut is disabled. Is there a way to flag my custom shortcut so that it is available from the lock screen, or to set it in gnome-screensaver?

Comment: There's some brainstorming about this here: [Allow media keys to function while the desktop is locked](http://askubuntu.com/q/122903/)

Answer (score 3):

The scope of lock screen is to lock any user to do something. This mean that you can't run a script in lock screen only if you schedule it to run from before.

Consequently, your shortcut key or any other shortcut will never work when your computer is in lock screen.