# Enable [Fn]+[cursor arrows] on lock/login screen to change volume and brightness

Tags: keyboard, brightness, login-screen, lock-screen, volume-control

Having a new Acer Aspire E17 E5-773G with Ubuntu 16.04 on it, I experience that the keyboard combinations to adjust volume (<kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd>/<kbd>↓</kbd>) and brightness (<kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd>) do not work on the login screen or lock screen.

They do work when logged in though, so it's not a general problem. What do I have to do to be able to use them from the login and lock screen as well?

Comment: possible duplicated ?? http://askubuntu.com/questions/122903/how-to-allow-key-functions-while-desktop-locked

Comment: I don't know if that helps someone to answer but on my Ubuntu-MATE I have the same problem. I noticed that when I right click on destkop or on some applications like caja, then adjusting brightness with the `Fn` keys doesn't work (while disabling wifi works) so it's like the pop up from right click blocks some `Fn` functionality but when I right click for example at chromium then it works just fine. Can you tell me the behavior when you right click on your desktop to see if it's somehow connected?

Comment: @ThanosApostolou I could not reproduce your described behaviour.

Comment: On Ubuntu GNOME I have this ability by default. Don't know about Unity though.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.4 LTS with budgie DE, same problem. It's a real pain...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and kernel parameters did not work for me. I wanted the keys to behave more like direct hardware buttons, so they worked regardless of login status, and also on **tty** screens. I got most of the solution via a third party site linked from [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/704141/how-to-get-my-brightness-volume-and-other-special-keys-to-work-in-a-tty), the various answers and comments on [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/149054/how-to-change-lcd-brightness-from-command-line-or-via-script), and the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/acpid). In summary, this listens to ACPI events with a system service, and sets the brightness directly.

Install the `acpid` package:

```sh
apt install acpid
```

Create `/etc/acpi/events/brightness`:

```ini
event=video/brightness(up|down)
action=/etc/acpi/brightness.sh %e
```

and `/etc/acpi/brightness.sh`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set -e

# edit this to match your device under /sys/class/backlight/
dev=amdgpu_bl0
# change if you want a different number of brightness levels
levels=16

case "$1" in
    video/brightnessup)
        chg=1
        ;;
    video/brightnessdown)
        chg=-1
        ;;
    *)
        exit 1
        ;;
esac

dev="/sys/class/backlight/$dev"
[[ -e "$dev" ]]
bri="$dev/brightness"
read -r cur < "$bri"
read -r max < "$dev/max_brightness"
max_levels=$(( max + 1 ))
if (( levels < 1 )); then
    levels=1
elif (( levels > max_levels )); then
    levels=$max_levels
fi
incr=$(( max_levels / levels ))
new=$(( cur + ( incr * chg ) ))
if (( new > max )); then
    new=$max
elif (( new < 0 )); then
    new=0
fi
if (( new != cur )); then
    echo $new > "$bri"
fi
```

and make it executable:

```sh
chmod +x /etc/acpi/brightness.sh
```

Restart and enable the service:

```sh
systemctl restart acpid && systemctl enable acpid
```

The final piece is to stop the double binding of the keys. In KDE Plasma, you can just disable the default bindings in *System Settings > Shortcuts > Power Management > Decrease/Increase Screen Brightness*. I assume other DEs have similar ability to ignore those keys.

Answer (score 0):

In the terminal:

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Change

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi="
```

Save, then

```
sudo update-grub
```

Restart computer.

Comment: I made the edit and updated GRUB, but there was no change. I still can't change the volume and brightness using my `Fn` keys from the log-in screen. I even confirmed that the change was active from the GRUB menu. It does not work. :-(

Comment: Set `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` to `"quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux"` and test again.

Comment: I just tried that, but without luck. No observable changes either, the volume/brightness key combinations still don't work.

Comment: try this config: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet acpi_backlight=vendor splash acpi_osi=linux"`

Comment: I have already tried this without luck as well.